# Suggestion for Tooth Chart Data Structure

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, wamp

Hello I'm not sure if this is an OK question here but here goes, I'm quite confused on how am I going to make the data structure of my tooth chart database.  I had first this thought of making a data structure like this

```
teeth_table 
teeth_id (Primary key)
teeth_1 (These are 32 tooth)
until teeth_32 (These are 32 tooth)
patient_id (Foreign key connected to the patient table)
```

my second plan is to make an individual table for each tooth (which will take a lot of time I guess?)

```
tooth01_table
tooth_id
tooth_name
tooth_condition
tooth_recommendation
tooth_treatment
patient_id
```

and that's all I thought,
my plan is to make a table where it would show the following when a patient selects a tooth from a dropdown list

Tooth | Condition | Recommendation | Treatment

So what do you guys think is a good design for a tooth chart database?

a tooth chart is like these

> http://www.mouthandteeth.com/img/FDI-tooth-numbering-system.gif

Answer (score 1):

I would so something like this.  I presume that your patients will visit more than once and you will need a data set for each visit.  Of course, you will need to add more columns, but this structure should allow for flexibility for reporting as well as data entry.

```
CREATE TABLE Teeth
(
ToothID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
, ToothPosition INT NOT NULL
, ToothType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Patient
(
PatientID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
, PatientName VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE PatientVisit
(
PatientVisitID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
, PatientID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Patient(PatientID)
, DateVisit DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE PatientTeeth
(
PatientTeethID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
, PatientVisitID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES PatientVisit(PatientVisitID)
, ToothID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Teeth(ToothID)
, ToothCondition VARCHAR(10) NULL
, ToothRecommendation VARCHAR(10) NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the number of teeth is nominally fixed in adults, there are pathologies which cause a higer or lower number.  Your first thought would not allow for this.  So I would go with the second approach.  This has the flexibility to deal with normal adult teeth, milk teeth and abnormal circumstances.

I would suggest these tables.

```
Patient
    ID
    Name
    Address etc.

Examination
    ExaminationID
    PatientID
    DateTime

ToothCondition
    ExaminationID
    ToothID        -- using the naming scheme from your linked image
    Condition      -- missing, erupted, crowned etc.
    Recommendation
    Treatment
    IsMissing      -- Yes/No

AdultTooth
    ToothID        -- using the naming scheme from your linked image
    SortSequence

MilkTooth
    ToothID
    SortSequence
```

For each new `Examination` copy forward all `ToothCondition` rows from the previous one.  The `AdultTooth` and `MilkTooth` tables are just convenience sets which can be copied to `Examination` for the first examination.

I have separated `IsMissing` as a special case of `Condition` to make it clear that it is the tooth that is absent and not the row in the table!